# Image File Upload 415 Unsupported Media Type Java Httpclient 4.4

Tags: java, file-upload, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-status-code-415

I am trying to do a POST request with 1 file object and 2 texts filed as below. But always getting **415 Unsupported Media Type**. I'm using httpclient 4.4.

**415 error is mean to mistake in body or header?**

```
HttpPost request= new HttpPost("https://mysite/v1/files");
request.addHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8");
request.addHeader("Authorization","Bearer <token>);
MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);`

File file = new File("/opt/productImages/productImage1.jpg");

builder.addTextBody("text", "productImage1.jpg", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
builder.addTextBody("text", "productImage", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
builder.addBinaryBody("upfile",uploadFile,ContentType.create("image/jpeg"),"productImage1.jpg");


HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpEntity entity = builder.build();
request.setEntity(entity);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
System.out.println(response);
```

is there any way to debug it more to get the exact error.